# Sencha Architect 4 - ExtJS 6.5 -> Dreamfactory 2.9 Authentication Session Token

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect, dreamfactory

I got a little bit stuck and I would like to ask your advice, I am trying to setup a login window // authentication using DreamFactory in Sencha Architect however I am pretty much a beginner.

My current Code is:

```
var username = Ext.getCmp('usr').getValue(),
password = Ext.getCmp('pwd').getValue();

Ext.Ajax.defaultHeaders = {
'X-DreamFactory-Api-Key' : 'xyz',
'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
};

Ext.Ajax.request({
url: 'http://dreamfactoryaddy:8080/api/v2/user/session',
withCredentials: true,
email: username,
password: password,
cors: true,

success: function(response) {
    var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
    Ext.Ajax.defaultHeaders = {
        'X-DreamFactory-Api-Key' : 
'xyz', 'Content-Type' : 'application/json', 'X-DreamFactory-Session-
Token': obj.session_token
    };
    console.log(obj);
},

failure: function(response) {
        console.log(response.responseText);
}

});
```

I receive this error:

```
{"error":{"code":401,"context":null,"message":"There is no valid session for the current request.","status_code":401}}
```

http://prntscr.com/hate2e

Can you give me some advice how to handle Sessions properly?

UPDATE 2:

```
            var username = Ext.getCmp('usr').getValue(),
                password = Ext.getCmp('pwd').getValue(),
                headers = {
                    'X-DreamFactory-Api-Key' : 'xyz',
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                };

            Ext.Ajax.setDefaultHeaders(headers);
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'http://chalton.swiftmedia.ca:8080/api/v2/user/session',
                withCredentials: true,
                jsonData: {
                    "email" : username,
                    "password" : password
                },
                cors: true,

                success: function(response) {
                    var obj = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText),
                        newheaders = {
                            'X-DreamFactory-Api-Key' : 'xyz',
                            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
                            'X-DreamFactory-Session-Token': obj.session_token
                        };
                    console.log(response.responseText);
                    Ext.Ajax.setDefaultHeaders(newheaders);
                },

                failure: function(response) {
                    console.log(response.responseText);
                }

            });
        },
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have enabled CORS for localhost in DreamFactory -> http://prntscr.com/hatj1v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the browser console, you may find that the `defaultHeaders` are not correctly applied to your ajax requests.

I had the very same issue with arbitrary other headers I wanted as the default headers. `Ext.Ajax.defaultHeaders = x` just doesn't work, `Ext.Ajax.setDefaultHeaders(x)` does.

Comment: Hey Alexander, I just tried it with the following code and it had the exact same result, what am I missing? I have added the updates to my original code.

Comment: The first header gets passed on but the second with the session_token does not. http://prntscr.com/hava87

Comment: I found the issue and updated my code above, it was not passing my request on as JSON. Thank you Alexander!