# How to add csrf token in ExtJS ajax call?

Tags: ajax, jsp, extjs, csrf, csrf-protection

In my application i have both JSP and JS using Ext JS 5.1. I need to apply spring csrf protection to my application.
In Jsp i was able to add it as below :

```
 <body>
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"  value="${_csrf.token}">
    </body>
```

But i am not sure how to do it in .js files? Do i have declare Meta tag for ext js too? I need to apply the csrf token to every ajax request.

Just to highlight, i have scanned many sites but did not got any proper explanation or working example. How to add csrf in ajax calls of Ext js .js file ?

Comment: `I need to apply the csrf token to every ajax request.` -> Maybe [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47310459/sencha-architect-4-extjs-6-5-dreamfactory-2-9-authentication-session-token/47311710#47311710) can help.

Comment: Hi @Alexander, My question is how should i read the _csrf.parameterName &  _csrf.token in .js file?

Comment: It seems to me that these are server variables that are replaced in the JSP by the server _before_ sending it to the client. So you have to get these values into the frontend through a server-side API. So the question would not be ExtJS-specific at all, and I came here for the ExtJS tag. You may want to ask a new question with the JSP tag on how to get CSRF values into a JSON API.

Comment: HI @Alexander, you are partially correct. But I am able read these variable in jsp successfully as mentioned in Question. I am facing issue to get these variable in extJS's .js files. So to be more specific, this question is "How to enable scrf in ExtJS 5.1 ? "

Answer (score -1):

I was able to do it as follows. Add below snippet to your app.js or Application.js of ext js application.

```
Ext.Ajax.on('beforerequest', function(conn, options) {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("META");
    var token = "";
    var headerVal = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i].name == "_csrf") {
            token = x[i].content;
        } else if (x[i].name == "_csrf_header") {
            headerVal = x[i].content;
        }
    }

    Ext.Ajax.setDefaultHeaders({
        headerVal: token
    });
});
```

OR

```
Ext.Ajax.on('beforerequest', function(conn, options) {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("META");
    var token = "";
    var headerVal = ""; 
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i].name == "_csrf")
        {
             token = x[i].content;
        }
    }

   // Ext.Ajax.defaultHeaders = Ext.apply(Ext.Ajax.defaultHeaders || {}, { headerVal : token });
    Ext.Ajax.setDefaultHeaders({
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN':token
    });
});
```

Comment: This solution still fails the Fortify scan.